# Semantic UI dropdown user addition only allow email address

Tags: javascript, jquery, semantic-ui

The dropdown is being used to allow the visitor to search for users/email addresses or enter in a custom email address.

I don't want them to be able to add a user addition unless it's a valid email address. Everything works in regards to the remote API call/search, and adding those, but i'm having one hell of a time trying to validate the user addition, and even trying to use some jQuery hacks after the user selects the item, which all failed me miserably.

Sounds simple, right? Well apparently not for me :(

Basically everything works except preventing them from adding a user addition if it's not a valid email address.

Here's a jsFiddle of everything:
http://jsfiddle.net/tripflex/zewxp49s/

```
var excludeHasResults = false;

$.fn.dropdown.settings.templates.addition = function(search) {

  var output = 'Search results for';

  if (!excludeHasResults) {
    output = 'No users found for';
  }

  // Add search value to output
  output += ' <strong>' + search + '</strong>.  ';

  // Add to end of output based on valid email or not
  if (is_valid_email(search)) {
    output += ' <em>Click here to add ' + search + '</em>';
  } else {
    output += 'Please enter a valid email to add a custom email address';
  }

  return output;
};

$('#users_dd').dropdown({
  allowAdditions: true,
  apiSettings: {
    response: {
      success: true,
      results: [{
        'name': 'someone@somewhere.com',
        'value': 'someone@somewhere.com'
      }, {
        'name': 'someone2@somewhere2.com',
        'value': 'someone2@somewhere2.com'
      }, ]
    },
    onComplete: function(response) {
      // Check response for results, needed to format no results/add custom template value
      if (response && response.success && response.results) {
        if ($(response.results).length > 0) {
          // Set to TRUE so when "add" template function is called, it returns the right template
          excludeHasResults = true;
        } else {
          excludeHasResults = false;
        }
      }
    },
  },
  debug: true,
  hideAdditions: false,
  minCharacters: 3,
  showNoResults: true,
  message: {
    // $.fn.dropdown.settings.templates.addition handles template output
    addResult: '{term}',
  },
  onAdd: function(addedValue, addedText, $addedChoice) {
    console.log('onAdd', addedValue, addedText, $addedChoice);
    console.log($addedChoice);

    if (!is_valid_email(addedValue)) {
      console.log('invalid email, removing');
      $(this).dropdown('remove selected', addedValue);
    }
  },
  onLabelCreate: function(value, text) {
    console.log('onLabelCreate', value, text);
    console.log($(this));
    return $(this);
  },
  onLabelSelect: function($selectedLabels) {
    console.log('onLabelSelect', $selectedLabels);
  },
  onNoResults: function(searchValue) {
    console.log('onNoResults', searchValue);
    // Set variable false for no results/add custom template output
    excludeHasResults = false;
    return true;
  },
});

// Just basic email validation
function is_valid_email(email) {
  var re = /\S+@\S+\.\S+/;
  return re.test(email);
}
```

This example allows any user addition, and after spending hours trying to use different methods, I can't figure out how to do a basic validation on the user addition and only allow if it's a valid email.

On top of the gazillion other things I tried, docs on onAdd say "Is called after a dropdown selection is added using a multiple select dropdown, only receives the added value" ... but yet it doesn't appear that way, if you view console you see that onLabelCreate is called after onAdd ... wtf??

Reason being, I tried to remove the dropdown after being added while in the onAdd callback, but that clearly doesn't work, like everything else I tried...

AHHHH please someone help me figure this out!

Comment: Every time I click on the text box or press a key on it, onComplete event fired. so just rewrite this function, show validation or something and change response object that created and filled by default right now, not users input!